# Symfony 1.4 Как оптимизировать производительность?

Tags: оптимизация, symfony

Привет друзья.

Если я вопрос задал неподходящий то пожалуйста укажите где его можно опубликовать на stackoverflow.

Мне как девелоперу достался сайт написан на этом <<чудесном>>  framework :)).

Я в жизни не занимался этим,и не представлял что симфони фрамеворк может такое натворить.

Раньше ,как хозяева сайта говорят, когда число пользователей было около 4-5 000 в день было нормально ,а теперь перевалило за 7000 и Процессор жрет все 100%.

На главной странице (`index.php`) весь контент буферизировал следующим образом

```
ob_start();
...
...
ob_end_flush();
```

Вроде помогло с загрузкой страницы,с базой данных все в порядке (оптимизирован). Но все равно через некоторое время опять вся память 100%

Пожалуйста помогите.
Может кто знает, как можно оптимизировать производительность symfony 1.4?

Comment: профилировать (и кешировать) уже пробовали?

Comment: @KoVadim Cache symfony 1.4 framework normalno delaet.Мне хотя бы глобальные правильные вещи сделать.Например удалил все файлы `htaccess` и перенёс в apache конфиг

Comment: перенос htaccess файлов в один конфиг вряд ли сильно изменить производительность. Ну раз в кешировании Вы уверены - тогда только профилируйте.

Comment: @KoVadim А как вы думаете `ob_start();`  мне чем то поможет ?

Comment: думаю, что немножко поможет. Поможет, если внутри скриптов есть тяжелый код и страница долго отдается (тут тонкая разница между отдается и рассчитывается). Но лучше ищите проблемы внутри кода. Может быть, база не выдерживает.